# Orderby not working when displaying records from firebase

Tags: flutter, dart, stream-builder, flutter-streambuilder

I am trying to display a list according to when it was created.
for some weird reason, the list is getting confused or something, because its displaying messages out of order.

the chat appears to be sorting alphabetically sometimes, not sure why.
the expected behavior should be that the messages are displayed like they are on phones

I added a video with how the messages are being displayed
https://youtu.be/w00cNi_uEa0

```
class Messages extends StatelessWidget {
  final currentUser = AuthService.firebase().currentUser!;
  User? _currentUser = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
  String chatId;
  Messages({required this.chatId});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('chat messages')
          .where('chatId', isEqualTo: chatId)
          .orderBy(
            'createdAt',
            descending: true,
          )
          .snapshots(),
      builder: (ctx, chatSnapshot) {
        if (chatSnapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return const Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          );
        }
        final chatDocs = chatSnapshot.data?.docs;
        // final isMe = chatDocs?[index]['userId'] == currentUser;

        return ListView.builder(
          // shrinkWrap: true,
          reverse: true,
          itemCount: chatDocs?.length,
          itemBuilder: (ctx, index) => MessageBubble(
            message: chatDocs?[index]['text'],
            isMe: chatDocs?[index]['userId'] == currentUser.id,
            key: ValueKey(chatDocs?[index].id),
            // userName: chatDocs?[index]['userId'],
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
``
```

Comment: i updated the title. Its hard to add details in the description since you kinda have to see it in action to how the messages are being displayed

Comment: That title is much more informative. Thanks!

Comment: it might be a problem sorting your data. try to write your date using this: `DateTime.now().toIso8601String()`, this works well for me.

Comment: also `DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString()` can help you sort by latest using timestamps.

Comment: or Alternatively use firebase timestamp.

Comment: it was something to do with the simulator.... when i tried it on the physical iphone everything worked... so weird